# Move Back Up XML Using Nodes

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I'm using the Nodes method to shred some XML data into a table, and I'm just missing one part. I need a particular XML element, but its back up (pardon my poor syntax, new to dealing with XML) the XML from where I'm shredding. I've posted, what I hope is all the relevant code:

XML :

```
<ToDoList xmlns="----.----.MappingObjects/XmlSchemas/ToDoList.xsd">
  <Step>
    <StepId>f3ab5132-fcf4-47c4-929f-ab7464d3bcc7</StepId>
    <Rank>1</Rank>
    <IsComplete>true</IsComplete>
    <CompletionDate>2017-04-17T17:12:45Z</CompletionDate>
    <CompletionUser>Michael Johnson</CompletionUser>
    <Text></Text>
    <CalibrationId>3</CalibrationId>
    <CalibrationValues>
      <Value>
        <Standard>1111</Standard>
        <UnitOfMeasureName>NewU</UnitOfMeasureName>
        <Min>1111</Min>
        <Normal>1112</Normal>
        <Max>1113</Max>
        <BeforeReading>1111</BeforeReading>
        <AfterReading>1112</AfterReading>
        <DateCalibrated>2017-04-17T17:12:00Z</DateCalibrated>
        <FailBefore>false</FailBefore>
        <FailAfter>false</FailAfter>
      </Value>
      <Value>
        <Standard>245.000</Standard>
        <UnitOfMeasureName>NewU</UnitOfMeasureName>
        <Min>245</Min>
        <Normal>250</Normal>
        <Max>280</Max>
        <BeforeReading>245</BeforeReading>
        <AfterReading>250</AfterReading>
        <DateCalibrated>2017-04-17T17:12:00Z</DateCalibrated>
        <FailBefore>false</FailBefore>
        <FailAfter>false</FailAfter>
      </Value>
    </CalibrationValues>
  </Step>
</ToDoList>
```

SQL :

```
;with XMLNAMESPACES('----.-----.MappingObjects/XmlSchemas/ToDoList.xsd' as NS)

select WOId,
       N.Step.value('(NS:Standard)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as [Standard],
       N.Step.value('(NS:UnitOfMeasureName)[1]','nvarchar(32)') as [UOM],
       N.Step.value('(NS:Min)[1]','float') as [Min],
       N.Step.value('(NS:Normal)[1]','float') as Normal,
       N.Step.value('(NS:Max)[1]','float') as [Max],
       N.Step.value('(NS:BeforeReading)[1]','float') as BeforeReading,
       N.Step.value('(NS:AfterReading)[1]','float') as AfterReading,
       dbo.fn_clr_GetCustomerLocalTimeFromUTC(@CUSTOMERTIMEZONE, N.Step.value('(NS:DateCalibrated)[1]','datetime')) as DateCalibrated,
       N.Step.value('(NS:FailBefore)[1]','bit') as FailBefore,
       N.Step.value('(NS:FailAfter)[1]','bit') as FailAfter


from tblWorkOrderToDoList WOTD
cross apply Data.nodes('//NS:Value') N(Step)
```

The existing table returns the following columns (shortened for brevity):

WOId Standard UOM Min Normal Max BeforeReading AfterReading DateCalibrated

What I'd like to see:

WOId CalibrationId Standard UOM Min Normal Max BeforeReading AfterReading

where the CalibrationId is (using the XML above) 3 for each returned row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can shred the XML twice, first on `Step` element level and then on `Value`, so that you can get necessary information from both elements :

```
select 
    WOId,
    T.Step.value('NS:CalibrationId[1]','int') as CalibrationId
    N.Value.value('NS:Standard[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as [Standard],
    N.Value.value('NS:UnitOfMeasureName[1]','nvarchar(32)') as [UOM],
    N.Value.value('NS:Min[1]','float') as [Min],
    ....
from tblWorkOrderToDoList WOTD
cross apply WOTD.Data.nodes('//NS:Step') T(Step)
cross apply T.Step.nodes('NS:CalibrationValues/NS:Value') N(Value)
```

Comment: Or probably without shredding twice using `..` to move up XML tree one level : `(../../NS:CalibrationId)[1]`